# How does Property() know what to do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

I'm new to Python, and I've just reached the OOP chapter in my programming textbook.

The textbook does not explain how `property()` works.

How does `property()` know to change the name to `new_name` and not `new_name + "lololol"`?

I created `set_name2` because I wanted to see how `property()` works. But to my surprise the name did not change to `new_name + "lololol"`.

```
# Property Critter

class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        print "A new critter has been born!"
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, new_name):
        if new_name == "":
            print "A critter's name can't be an empty string."
        else:
            self.__name = new_name
            print "Name change successful."

    def set_name2(self, new_name):
        self.__name = new_name + "lololol"
        print "Name change successful (set_name2!)"

    name = property(get_name, set_name, set_name2)

    def talk(self):
        print "\nHi, I'm", self.name


# main

crit = Critter("Poochie")
crit.talk()
print "\nMy critter's name is:",
print crit.name
print "\nAttempting to change my critter's name."
crit.name = ""
print "\nAttempting to change my critter's name again."
crit.name = "Randolph"

crit.talk()

raw_input("\n\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Comment: Read this then: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I have just read that webpage but I cannot find a simple explanation there.

Comment: If you know the basics of Python classes then that's the best explanation IMO. And please ask a specific question, you're kind of asking for a tutorial on properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, how does the @property decorator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/python-how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Answer (score 2):

The third argument for `property` is expected to be a function that **deletes** the property, not another setter function (the name of the function has no special meaning, just naming it `set_something` doesn't make it a setter). The [official documentation of property](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) has good explanation of what `fget`, `fset` and `fdel` are expected to do.

To understand *how* `property` works internally, you can read about [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/descriptor.html) as pointed by Ashwini Chaudhary.

Here is a little modification of your code to illustrate the `property` behavior:

```
# Property Critter

class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        print "A new critter has been born!" 
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, new_name):
        if new_name == "":
            print "A critter's name can't be an empty string." 
        else:
            self.__name = new_name
            print "Name change successful." 

    def del_name(self):
        self.__name = "Scratchy"
        print "If you don't give me a name, I will choose one myself!" 

    name = property(get_name, set_name, del_name)

    def talk(self):
        print "\nHi, I'm", self.name 


# main

crit = Critter("Poochie")
crit.talk()
print "\nMy critter's name is:",
print crit.name 
crit.name = ""
crit.name = "Itchy"
crit.talk()
del crit.name
crit.talk()
```

Which outputs:

```
A new critter has been born!

Hi, I'm Poochie

My critter's name is: Poochie
A critter's name can't be an empty string.
Name change successful.

Hi, I'm Itchy
If you don't give me a name, I will choose one myself!

Hi, I'm Scratchy
```